# C# get Object Property by name

Tags: c#

In other languages like JavaScript I can use for example:

```js
const obj = { a: 5 };
obj["a"] //returns 5
```

Is it possible to get an object property if it's name is given as string in C#? I don't want a giant if/else tree

Comment: You can use reflection - but this may well not be the best approach. You may be better off just using a dictionary. Without knowing anything about the bigger context, it's hard to say.

Comment: I'm trying to edit an item in the list where I receive the edited property name as a string

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! I don't know how I didn't stumble upon this when googling

Comment: I would not recommend reflection, you can simply create a dictionary and obtain the value using the key associated to it.

Comment: This is an XY problem, C# is a typed language and nothing like JavaScript. I suggest learning how to use it as a typed language and you might have a much easier time.. Or if you want, add more information about the problem you are actually trying to solve, you might find people can suggest better solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
 var obj = new { A = 5 } as object; // your object

 var five = obj.GetType().GetProperty("A").GetValue(obj);
```

Also, you can use dynamic:

```
var fiveDynamic = (obj as dynamic).A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, of course

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

but you'll get much more new problems than you'll solve. The main is: you don't know the type of the value. It doesn't matter in Javascript, but you cannot say the same about C#.
If you are sure to make one more step to make your code a mess, do this

```
var type = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetType();
var value = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);

Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
```

Comment: "_you don't know the type of the value_" Why assume that? The compiler doesn't know the type, but the developer might. Also `Convert.ChangeType` achieves nothing here; your getting the type of the object using reflection, then converting the object to the type that it already is. You are probably looking for a cast, but in that case the developer _does_ claim to know the type.